# Pandas Merge by Overlapping Ranges in Both DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, merge, range

Given the following:

```
import pandas as pd
a=pd.DataFrame({' ID':[1,1,2,2],'a.A':[1,5,10,15],'a.B':[3,8,13,18]})
b=pd.DataFrame({' ID':[1,1,2,2],'b.A':[2,2,14,18],'b.B':[3,2,15,20]})
a
    ID  a.A     a.B
0   1     1     3
1   1     5     8
2   2     10    13
3   2     15    18

b
    ID  b.A     b.B
0   1     2     3
1   1     2     2
2   2     14    15
3   2     18    20
```

I need to left join b to a where the range of a.A to a.B overlaps with that of b.A to b.B for a given ID number. The logic can also be explained like this:
If ID matches between a and b, then if (a.A <= b.A and a.B >= b.A) or (a.A <= b.B and a.B >= b.B) then match.

The final result would look like this:

```
    ID   a.A     a.B    b.A   b.B
0   1      1       3     2      3
1   1      1       3     2      2
2   1      5       8        
3   2     10      13        
4   2     15      18    18     20
5   2     15      18    18     20
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that the correct output you want? I am not sure about line 4. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a=pd.DataFrame({' ID':[1,1,2,2],'a.A':[1,5,10,15],'a.B':[3,8,13,18]})
b=pd.DataFrame({' ID':[1,1,2,2],'b.A':[2,2,14,18],'b.B':[3,2,15,20]})

c = a.merge(b, on=' ID', how='left')
range_overlaps = (
    ((c['a.A'] <= c['b.A']) & (c['a.B'] >= c['b.A'])) |
    ((c['a.A'] <= c['b.B']) & (c['a.B'] >= c['b.B']))
)
c.loc[~range_overlaps, ['b.A', 'b.B']] = np.nan
c = c.drop_duplicates()
c = c.reset_index(drop=True)

print(c)
```

gives:

```
    ID  a.A  a.B   b.A   b.B
0    1    1    3   2.0   3.0
1    1    1    3   2.0   2.0
2    1    5    8   NaN   NaN
3    2   10   13   NaN   NaN
4    2   15   18  14.0  15.0
5    2   15   18  18.0  20.0
```

Comment: Both excellent responses. I might drop b.A where NaN instead of using drop duplicates in case I have more than one match with the same numbers in both columns. Many thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this is the best solution, but it can be a good start:

```
import pandas as pd
a=pd.DataFrame({' ID':[1,1,2,2],'a.A':[1,5,10,15],'a.B':[3,8,13,18]})
b=pd.DataFrame({' ID':[1,1,2,2],'b.A':[2,2,14,18],'b.B':[3,2,15,20]})

c = a.merge(b)
cbAB = (c["a.A"] <= c["b.A"]) & (c["a.B"] >= c["b.A"]) | (c["a.A"] <= c["b.B"]) & (c["a.B"] >= c["b.B"])
cb = c[["b.A","b.B"]]
cb = cb[cbAB]
c[["b.A","b.B"]] = cb

c = c.drop_duplicates()
```

Output for `c` is:

```
>>> c
    ID  a.A  a.B  b.A  b.B
0    1    1    3    2    3
1    1    1    3    2    2
2    1    5    8  NaN  NaN
4    2   10   13  NaN  NaN
6    2   15   18   14   15
7    2   15   18   18   20
```